# Is there a better command line tool than check_urdf?

Tags: ros, urdf

When I am working on my robot's URDF (for ROS2 GoPiGo3 robot), I edit the URDF (in a command shell/nano to the robot), then run check_urdf.  check_urdf will often tell me the line in the check_urdf source code where an error occurs but not the line in my URDF file.

I do not have remote VSCode or a graphical environment set up on my robot, so am looking for a command-line tool for checking URDF files that is better or will augment the ROS check_urdf tool.

I run the robot state and joint state publishers on my robot, not on the visualization platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect xml errors, you can use the `xmllint` tool. You can also pass a URDF file to `gz sdf --check <file>`, which will convert the file to SDFormat and then check it, but that's probably not exactly what you're looking for.